# npm autocomplete broken if prefixed by double dash (--)

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, npm

I notice this when using a command that accepts additional args after a double-dash, for example:

```
npm test -- spec/blah-spec.js
```

In a raw, clean, ZSH v5.3 install, tab-completion works properly:

```
npm test -- spec/blah<TAB>
```

But, as soon as I add the following lines to my .zshrc:

```
autoload -U compinit && compinit
zmodload -i zsh/complist
```

The tab-completion in that case breaks (TAB does nothing).

Is there a way to both have custom completions and not break this use case?

UPDATE: per suggestion:

```
❯ which $_comps[npm]
_npm_completion () {
    local si=$IFS 
    compadd -- $(COMP_CWORD=$((CURRENT-1)) \
                 COMP_LINE=$BUFFER \
                 COMP_POINT=0 \
                 npm completion -- "${words[@]}" \
                 2>/dev/null)
    IFS=$si 
}
```

Comment: Do you have problems with commands other than `npm`? Do you have the same problem without loading `zsh/complist`? The npm completion code is distributed with npm, not with zsh. It's changed over time, too. What's the output of `which $_comps[npm]` after attempting one completion?

Comment: Ah, @Gilles, you are right - I thought it was any use of "--" but it looks like other commands (grunt etc) work fine.  Only npm does not.